# BorderFactory and Metal L&F issues

Tags: java, swing, border

I am seeing a strange behaviour. The L&F set is Metal.

> UIManager.setLookAndFeel("javax.swing.plaf.metal.MetalLookAndFeel");

If I set a Border border1 on a JPanel, then I change the Border to border2 on the same JPanel, when a tooltip passes on border2, repaint redraws border1. This occurs on L&F Metal only, with LineBorder, TitledBorder....

Comment: Post your [mcve] demonstrating the problem.

Comment: OK I have done it. There are 6 java classes, a runnable jar and an explanation text. Where do I post this little Eclipse project?

Comment: Where should I post my  Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example demonstrating the problem ?

Comment: We are not interested in your Eclipse project. We are not interested in 6 classes. You said you have a JPanel and a Border. So post a simple application with a JFrame, a JPanel and a Border that demonstrates the problem. The purpose of the "MCVE" is to simplify the problem to make it easy to understand and easier to debug. Chance are that while trying to create the "MCVE" you will discover the problem. The code should be posted with your question.

Comment: I did not mean I have one JPanel, I meant a series of JPanel, like on a chessboard.

Comment: So are the 64 panels relevant to the problem? Did you test it with one panel and then two panels to see if you have the same problem.  The point is you should do basic debugging BEFORE you ask the question so you only include relevant information in the question. If you can't post an "MCVE" then I can't help.

Comment: Yes I did try with 2, 3 ... 64 panels, the same issue happens in Metal L&F only. I am posting the code below , lighten to the max. Thank you for your attention. Charles.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> happens in Metal L&F only.

You still have a problem even if you don't specifically set the LAF.

> If I set a Border border1 on a JPanel, then I change the Border to border2 on the same JPanel, when a tooltip passes on border2, repaint redraws border1

It has nothing to do with the tooltip.

Just click on a couple of squares and then resize the frame, and all the Borders get repainted blue.

The problem is your `ColorsBoard` class.

You should NOT be overriding the `paintComponent()` method to create components.

***A painting method is only used for painting.***

The paintComponent() method is called whenever Swing determines a component needs to be repainted. This is why resizing the frame also causes the problem. You are recreating all the components.

The solution:

1. Don't override the paintComponent() method!
2. create all the components in the constructor of your class
3. Don't use a null layout. Instead use a GridLayout on the panel and just add your squares to the grid.
4. use `setBackground(Color.LIGHT_GRAY)` in the constructor to set the background

Also:

1. get rid of all the `synchronized` keywords on your methods. They are not needed.
2. Don't use "==" to compare Objects. Use the `equals(...)` method.

Answer (score 0):

```
public class BorderTest {

private JFrame jFrame;
private Container contentPane;
private ColorsBoard colorsBoard;

public BorderTest() {
    super();

    ToolTipManager.sharedInstance().setInitialDelay(10);
    ToolTipManager.sharedInstance().setDismissDelay(1500);
    jFrame = new JFrame();

    contentPane = jFrame.getContentPane();
    contentPane.setLayout(new BorderLayout());

    jFrame.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(700, 500));
    colorsBoard = new ColorsBoard();
    contentPane.add(colorsBoard, BorderLayout.CENTER);

    JLabel label = new JLabel(""
            + "<html>Click two or three small squares. <br/>"
            + "LineBorder's are set. <br/>"
            + "Then pass the tooltips over the red borders. <br/>"
            + "The red LineBorders' are back to blue. <br/>"
            + "This phenomen appears only in Metal L&F. </html>");
    contentPane.add(label, BorderLayout.EAST);

    jFrame.pack();
    jFrame.setVisible(true);
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
     try {
            UIManager.setLookAndFeel("javax.swing.plaf.metal.MetalLookAndFeel");

        new BorderTest();
    } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
}

class ColorsBoard extends JPanel {

private int squareSize = 315;
private int horizontal = 8;    //number of squares H
private int vertical = 8;      //number of squares V

private SquaredPanel[] squarePanels;   
int index = 0;
public int lastClickedSquare = -1;

// the chess board like JPanel.

public ColorsBoard() {
    squarePanels= new SquaredPanel[horizontal * vertical];
    this.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(squareSize, squareSize));
    setLayout(null);
}

// fill with squares (SquaredPanel)

protected synchronized void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
    super.paintComponent(g);

    int tileSizeH = squareSize / horizontal;
    int tileSizeV = squareSize / vertical;

    g.setColor(Color.LIGHT_GRAY);
    g.fillRect(0, 0, getWidth(), getHeight());

    for(int i = 0; i < horizontal*vertical; i++) {
        squarePanels[i] = new SquaredPanel(this);
    }

    index = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < horizontal; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < vertical; j++) {
                if(index == horizontal * vertical) break;
                    squarePanels[index].setBackground(Color.gray);
                    squarePanels[index].setSize(tileSizeH - 1, tileSizeV - 1);
                    squarePanels[index].setLocation(i * tileSizeH, j * tileSizeV);
                    squarePanels[index].setName("index " + index);
                    squarePanels[index].setIndex(index);
                    add(squarePanels[index]);
                    index++;
            }
        }
    }

public void eraseLastBlueBorder(int lastClickedSquare2) {
    if (lastClickedSquare == -1) {
        lastClickedSquare = lastClickedSquare2;
        return;
    }
    if(!squarePanels[lastClickedSquare].isRed)(squarePanels[lastClickedSquare]).cleanBorder();
    lastClickedSquare = lastClickedSquare2;
}
}

class SquaredPanel extends JPanel {

private String name;
protected Boolean isRed = false;
private int index;
private Border theBorder =  (new LineBorder(Color.gray, 2));

protected Border getTheBorder() {
    return theBorder;
}

public SquaredPanel(ColorsBoard colorsBoard) {
    super();

    addMouseListener(new MouseListener(){
        public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {
        }
        public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e) {
        }
        public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent e) {
            colorsBoard.eraseLastBlueBorder(index);
            setTitleBorder("RED");
        }
        public void mouseEntered(MouseEvent e) {
            setToolTipText(name);
        }
        public void mouseExited(MouseEvent e) {
            setToolTipText(null);
        }
      });
}

// the setBorder call
    protected void setTitleBorder(String title) {
        theBorder = (new LineBorder(title == "BLUE" ? Color.red : Color.blue, 2));
        setBorder(theBorder);
    }


public synchronized void cleanBorder() {
    setTitleBorder("BLUE");
}

public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
}

public void setIndex(int k) {
    index = k;
}
}
```

Comment: This is NOT an answer. You were asked to include the code with your question!